# Query LIKE on date type

Tags: sql

I am doing queries on the free DB of W3School and I have to do a query where I print every record that has year = 1996, month = 07 and any day.

I searched and I tried this form:

```
SELECT Customers.Country
FROM Customers, Orders
WHERE Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
AND (DATEPART(yy, OrderDate) = 1996
AND DATEPART(mm, OrderDate) = 07);
```

But it doesn't work...

I can use this form:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN #07/15/1996# AND #07/31/1996#;
```

but this still don't know why other forms don't work!

Comment: you sure it's not yyyy for a four-digit year-number like 1996? (DATEPART(yyyy, OrderDate) = 1996 ...

Comment: what is the error you get. Or what is your expected output and what did u actually get

Comment: It prints nothing. I expect as I wrote, all the records that has year=1996 and moth=07. I tried also with year and not yy and month and not mm but still not working

Comment: Can you show us some of your data you work with ? Just one value from OrderDate column that you expect to show in your result ?

Comment: The database is available online here [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all)
Btw the date is like month/day/year
The result of my query is this message: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that w3schools actually uses SQL-lite for their editor and then this would work:

```
SELECT c.Country
FROM Customers c
join Orders o on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
where strftime('%Y', o.OrderDate) = '1996'
and strftime('%m', o.OrderDate) = '07'
```

I would like to give you few advice's with this code:

1. Use aliases for your tables (aliases are this letters c and o and they are used so the code can be more readable. If you can use something with more sense than one letter do it like that, for example cust for customers or ord for orders table).
2. Use modern join like this:

   ```
   FROM Customers c
   join Orders o on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
   ```

   and not like this:

   ```
   FROM Customers, Orders
   WHERE Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
   ```
3. You do not need to put this two `AND` conditions inside brackets.
4. To make this work result of strftime function needs to be compared with values between single quotes. This is tested and works here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

[image]

I have also installed **Firefox** on my PC (Firefox is under "WebSQL Browser Support") and this is the code that works on Firefox:

```
SELECT c.Country
FROM Customers c, Orders o 
where c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
and year(o.OrderDate) = 1996
and month(o.OrderDate) = 7
```

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your tips.
BTW I used this query and this DB says that there is an error in the FROM clause.

Comment: Hi @alessandro_pier , please explain to me how ? I click on the link you provided in your comment "The database is available online here link " I copy and paste my code and run the code. All is ok.

Comment: am trying a query on W3School that works but DOESN'T work on another computer. I really don't know why... To be sure I did a query on date and I see it like this: "Month/Day/Year" but my friend sees it in this way: "Year-Month-Day"... So due to this thing some quaries don't works always...

Comment: Hi @alessandro_pier, can you tell me do you use same web browser ?

Comment: I use Firefox browser. You?

Comment: When you go to this link: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all please click on the black question mark at the end of the page and tell me what browsers does w3school editor supports ? Firefox is not among them, well it is but it is marked as unsupported. Please use one of the supported and this will work.

Comment: Yeah! You're right! It says that my browser (Firefox) doesn't support WebSQL

Comment: Yes, so please try with one of the supported browser because when you use Firefox you will use another version as it is noted at the end: "If you use another browser you will still be able to use our Try SQL Editor, but a different version, using a server-based ASP application, with a read-only Access Database, where users are not allowed to make any changes to the data."

Comment: Hi @alessandro_pier I have installed Firefox and I have updated my answer with the code that will work on Firefox too... Cheers!

Comment: Just missclicked

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, this learning platform seems to be running a vendor-agnostic SQL system. Apparently you only have access to the most basic functions like SELECT, UPDATE, that is the standard commands that work on every system.

The functions available, including date functions vary depending on the DBMS.
Either clarify the DBMS in use, or find another platform.

Of course, to extract months, years from dates they should be stored as `date`, or `datetime` and not as strings.

There is another downside to using functions like `DATEPART`: you will not be able to use **indexes** and the queries will take a long time on large tables because they will require a full table scan.

Assuming there is an index on OrderDate, a clause like this could take advantage of the index:

```
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '1996-07-01' AND '1996-07-31'
```

or:

```
WHERE OrderDate >= '1996-07-01' AND OrderDate <= '1996-07-31'
```

To sum up, you need to know what you are working on. Only then, you will be able to establish what functions are available to you. Again, it seems to be a trimmed-down environment where you won't be able to achieve much.

Comment: Hi, strftime function works, I believe it is SQL-lite as I have noted in my answer...

Comment: Unless I am missing something, your example does not work on the w3schools site.

Comment: I do not understand, My code works like a charm here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all I have even added the picture showing the same ...

Comment: Guys I am trying a query on W3School that works but DOESN'T work on another computer. I really don't know why... To be sure I did a query on date and I see it like this: "Month/Day/Year" but my friend sees it in this way: "Year-Month-Day"...
So due to this thing some quaries don't works always...

Comment: This is MS Access syntax for dates.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the strfttime() function for this. Pass '%m' for a monthly search or '%y' for a yearly search.

```
SELECT Customers.Country
FROM Customers, Orders
WHERE Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
AND strfttime('%y', OrderDate) = 1996
AND strfttime('%m', OrderDate) = 07;
```

Comment: It says: "Undefined function 'strfttime' in expression."

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with the IDE you're using.

Comment: As i said I am using the free database of W3School [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all)

Comment: W3School is using WebSQL, it looks like that does not support these functions. You can try this free editor https://sqliteonline.com/

Comment: Hi @PrateekSharma, There are two things  wrong in your answer: 1 . it is strftime and not strfttime 2. 1996 and 07 should be between single quotes. One more thing, it is not %y with small y it is %Y with capital Y. So 3 things are not good with your example.

Comment: SELECT demoDateColumn
FROM demo
WHERE year(demoDateColumn) = 2020
AND month(demoDateColumn) = 01;

Comment: Not working... but gives a clue on the backend: `The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query 'demo'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.`

Comment: "demo" is the table I created in my local machine, you can replace that with your table and column name.